# problem running simple demo example google-maps-services-js with Node

Tags: node.js, google-maps

I have a problem running this simple demo example for google-maps-service with Node:
https://github.com/jpoehnelt/google-maps-services-js-demo

I am not sure what I am missing. When I run `npm start`, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'elevation' of undefined
    at D:\node_practice\google-maps-services-js-demo\index.js:14:35
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

I am using nvm and my node version is 13.9.0. I tried it on two different machines (one windows with above node version, one ubuntu) and both got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems the response coming back is empty. your r.data is empty, which means results[0] is undefined, so is the reason you are getting `Cannot read property 'elevation' of undefined`.

Below is the actual exception coming back from the APIs

```
 "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account"
```

Get the instruction of getting an API key from here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-api-key
and use the same with your code.

Comment: Thanks! Now I see that the problem was with the API key.